# How to properly use loadtest4j

Tags: java, load-testing

I'm trying to use loadtest4j for load testing my application, but I have some problems with understanding how it works. Basically, how it setup, because I've followed guide step-by-step and can't setup driver to execute test.
As I understand, It's necessarily to apply driver, because raw loadtest4j didn't have standart driver, at least nothing is said about it in guide.

Has anyone use this library and can help me with that?

Comment: A little bit more information.
I followed guide for Gatling driver and import it by Maven. Then I used factory method, because for some reason IDEA didn't want to see GatlingBuilder from loadtest4j-gatling.
After all when i tried to start test I reached this exception:
"org.loadtest4j.LoadTesterException: No load test drivers were found on the classpath. Please add one to your project."

Comment: Hi Stanislav, would you be able to update your question with a copy of your pom.xml? And also a snippet of how you are constructing your LoadTester instances in your code. (These will help to reveal where the problem is.)

Comment: Additionally, if you have further questions about loadtest4j, you can ask in the Gitter channel at https://gitter.im/loadtest4j/community

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will check it after my military service in army.